# Python: How to write an XML file with '>' symbol in it

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have a xml file with content of the type:

```
<Column Name="name">
      <Definition>a>b</Definition>
</Column>
```

I parse this xml file using xml.etree.ElementTree in python. Then I write back the xml file using tree.write("sample.xml")

The output I get is

```
<Column Name="name">
      <Definition>a &gt; b</Definition>
</Column>
```

I want it to output the greater than symbol, like this:

```
<Column Name="name">
      <Definition>a > b</Definition>
</Column>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Curious as to the use case for this

Comment: The > has to be escaped in XML. Otherwise it's not well-formed. The only other option is to use a CDATA section: `<Definition><![CDATA[a > b]]></Definition>`. Not sure how to do that with Python though.